# Import SQL server type data into Oracle?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, database-migration

I was trying to import data from sql to oracle and the only way I found was Oracle SQL Developer. Finally I gave up. Today I heard someone said there is a format which I can do it in table level only. but she couldn't remember the format. It is something like CVN or CSV or something similar. Anyone has heard about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they were talking about was the [Bulk Load Utility](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14899_01/doc.9102/e14763/bulkload.htm) using a [.CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_valuesWc) file format.

Comment: Yes you're right, thanks for that, if you have any resource that I can import table from SQL please let me know.